# subprocess called proses error

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

i try program imalse , the following python script like that :

```
**#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
This is shortcut command to run simulate.py in ns3 ./waf shell
"""
import settings
import sys
import subprocess
cmd = settings.ROOT + '/simulate.py ' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
# print cmd
waf_cmd = ['cd', settings.NS3_PATH, '&&', './waf', '--pyrun', '"%s"'%(cmd)]
# subprocess.check_call(['cd', settings.NS3_PATH, '&&', './waf', '--pyrun', '"%s"'%(cmd)])
print '--> %s'%(' '.join(waf_cmd))
subprocess.check_call(' '.join(waf_cmd), shell=True)**
```

and the error like that :

```
Command ['/usr/bin/python', '/home/kelompok6/new/imalse/simulate.py'] exited with code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sim", line 16, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(' '.join(waf_cmd), shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cd /home/kelompok6/new/ns-allinone-3.14.1-with-imalse/ns-3.14.1 && ./waf --pyrun "/home/kelompok6/new/imalse/simulate.py "' returned non-zero exit status 1
kelompok6@kelompok6:~/new/imalse$ clear
```

what should i do?

Comment: `"/home/kelompok6/new/imalse/simulate.py "` - this path really exists in your system?

Comment: How is the error if you call `subprocess.check_call(['cd', settings.NS3_PATH, '&&', './waf', '--pyrun', '"%s"'%(cmd)])` instead? *not running it through the shell*.

Comment: 1- use `cwd` parameter instead of `cd` 2- drop `shell=True` and pass the command as a list (one list item per one command-line argument). If you don't understand what a command-line argument is, pass the complete command as a string to `shlex.split()` and see the result (you might need to adjust it). Remember to remove unnecessary quotes i.e., don't do `'"arg 1"'` (quote within quotes), do this instead: `'arg 1'`. 3- don't use `./waf`—provide the full path instead.